# Two queries in one statement

Tags: php, oracle

I'm using php and want to run two update queries in the one statement for oracle.

```
$x = strtolower($x);
$ore = getOreType($x); //returns ore type as string
$newTotal = getMined($ore)-($x_value*$weight); //adds existing ore quantity to additional quantity
$newTotalComp = $x_value + getComponentQuantity($x); //adds existing component quantity to additional quantity
$query = "UPDATE Material SET quantity=$newTotal WHERE name='$ore'; UPDATE Component SET   quantity=$newTotalComp WHERE name='$x'";
$statement = ociparse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($statement);
oci_free_statement($statement);
```

I'm getting the following error on oci_execute....

```
 oci_execute(): ORA-00911: invalid character
```

Is it possible to run both updates in the same statement? It works in Oracle SQL Developer.

Ta

Comment: **1-** I've set the timer **2-** Opened google and pasted that error **3-** I opened a link randomly and got [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204903/using-oci-parse-and-oci-execute). You basically can't use `;` which means you can't use two statements ? I came to this conclusion in less than 1mn. Do some research please.

Comment: No, you can't, because that's how the client library works. This actually true of most (all?) of the database drivers for PHP, MySQLi supports it but only if you call a [special function specifically for that job](http://php.net/mysqli-multi-query) (not that it would help you here, obviously). However, it may be possible to squash the two queries in a single operation using `JOIN`s if you can show more information about your DB schema and how these two tables relate to each other

Comment: Also, your code is wide open to SQL injection - you seem to be using a prepared statement (`oci_parse()`) but still not binding the values to placeholders...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

```
$query = "UPDATE Material,Component 
          SET Material.quantity=$newTotal , Component.quantity=$newTotalComp 
          WHERE Material.name='$ore' AND  Component.name='$x'";
```